# change Elastic Beanstalk docker build timeout option

Tags: docker, deployment, dockerfile, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, npm-install

I am using Elastic Beanstalk with Docker platform.

When i deploy to EB, it shows docker build failure log with docker build timeout.
[image]
[image]
i guess my project needs more time to build dockerfile.

so i want increase docker build timeout option on EB.

I tried to write `.ebextensions/increase-timeout.config` file with following option settings

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command
    option_name: Timeout
    value: 1000
```

It just increase EB command timeout option not the docker build timeout.

how can i change EB docker build timeout option ? ?

Comment: Finally i migrate Elastic Beanstalk project to EKS ...

Comment: Any answer on this? I'm facing the same problem and beanstalk definitely doesn't change the timeout value. My deploy fail after 300 seconds when using docker + ecr